# IsDBNull in Parameter AddWithValue

Tags: sql, vb.net, isnull

Aim: I want to check if the value is `Null` and it is then add blank otherwise add data

Issue: I am unsure on what I need to put after the first comma to change the `Null` to `""` and also then if it actually has data to import that instead

```vb
    With commandSQL
    .Connection = connection
    .CommandText = "spAddCSVDataLine"  'Stored procedure here
    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", (IsDBNull(ds.Tables("dataExcel").Rows(j)("Name"))),"",Trim(ds.Tables("dataExcel").Rows(j)("Name"))))
```

I can do the following but I would like to tighten the code up onto one line if possible:

```vb
If IsDBNull(ds.Tables("dataExcel").Rows(j)("Name")) Then
.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", "")
Else
.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", Trim(ds.Tables("dataExcel").Rows(j)("Name")))
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `If` operator:

```vb
With commandSQL
    .Connection = connection
    .CommandText = "spAddCSVDataLine"  'Stored procedure here
    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", If(IsDBNull(ds.Tables("dataExcel").Rows(j)("Name")), "", Trim(ds.Tables("dataExcel").Rows(j)("Name"))))
End With
```

Comment: Isn't inline If `IIF`?

Comment: That's If operator, not If statement.

Comment: @Obsidian Phoenix, no IIf is a method that has been included in VB.NET since the first version.  The If operator was added in VB 2008 I think it was.  Because it is an operator and not a method, it is able to short-circuit, i.e. it only evaluates the third operand if it's needed, just as the C# ternary ?: operator does.

Comment: @AaronPalmer huh, learn something new every day. I tend to avoid `IIF` in general, but was unaware of using `IF` inline.

Answer (score 3):

```vb
Dim row = ds.Tables("dataExcel").Rows(j)

.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", If(row.IsNull("Name"), String.Empty, CStr(row("Name"))))
```